# calling method within another method

Tags: java

I want to call the method getvertex() repeatedly within Model (example of one call shown ) but I get the error cannot find symbol: variable model on compiling. If I just simply put the code from getvertex in Model it works but is not practical for multiple calls. Can someone show me how to do this properly?

```
import com.comsol.model.*;
import com.comsol.model.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class trial
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  { 
    run();
  }

  public static Model run()
  {
    Model model = ModelUtil.create("Model");
    model.modelPath("C:\\R13\\WIN\\DWG");
    model.name("AMK.mph");
    model.modelNode().create("mod1");

    model.param().set("StripArea", ".000019217284 [m*m]");
    getvertex();
    return model;
  }

  public static void getvertex()
  {
    int ia = 1;
    String S1 = "";
    String C = "C";
    model.param().set(C + String.valueOf(ia), S1);
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: what is model.param().set(...)?

Answer (score 4):

Your `getvertex` method (which should be renamed `getVertex`) has no model variable inside of its scope and so cannot call any methods on this object. To solve this, you need to pass in a Model object parameter into the `getVertex` method and then call methods on that parameter. i.e.,

```
public void getVertex(Model model) {
  model.callSomeModelMethod();
}
```

Please consider formatting your code for this site better so that it is readable.